# Listing all friend requests using django-friendship

Tags: python, django

I was going to create my own friendship view and everything (But I couldn't figure out how to get everything working in a database) So I opted to use something called django-friendship which seems quite good, and It also came with tags to use in the HTML templates but now I am trying to list all the friend requests I can't seem to do a for statement in the tag which is:

```
{% friend_requests request.user %}
```

What I would like to be able to do is

```
{for friend_requests in request.user}
#show this then that#
```

the link to the github page for the project is this: https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship

If it comes to it I would prefer to create my own friendship implementation, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `friend_requests` tag uses a template, which already loops through and creates a list for you:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('friendship/templatetags/friend_requests.html')
def friend_requests(user):
    """
    Inclusion tag to display friend requests
    """
    return {'friend_requests': Friend.objects.requests(user)}
```

[source](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/master/friendship/templatetags/friendshiptags.py#L54)

Here is the template

```
<ul>
    {% for friend_request in friend_requests %}
        <li>{{ friend_request }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[source](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/master/friendship/templates/friendship/templatetags/friend_requests.html)

To customize it, create a directory `friendship` and inside it another one called `templatetags`, and then create a file called `friend_requests.html` in your app's template directory, and then you can customize the output there.

Comment: How would I replace the id's in the list with usernames?

Comment: Please ask a separate question, since others may have it and it is easier to find that way. StackOverflow works differently - each question should have one answer; and unlike forums there isn't a list of follow-ups or threaded replies.

Comment: ah, thanks for clearing that up for me. sorry for any inconvenience.